# How to stay logged in with iOS Facebook SDK 2.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm implementing Facebook login in my app using `FBSDKLoginManager`. [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.4#login-apicalls) seem to imply that this saves the token for subsequent app launches so that the user doesn't have to log in each time:

> The FBSDKLoginManager sets this token for you and when it sets currentAccessToken it also automatically writes it to a keychain cache.

I've been trying to retrieve this token from said cache when the app launches, or display my app's Facebook login screen if it can't be found:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];

    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        // user is logged in, continue to app's main screen
    } else {
        // show login screen
    }

    //...
}
```

This shows the login screen every single time. Facebook documentation doesn't explain how this very simple use case should be handled. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call "[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions]" BEFORE trying to get cached token.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

...